# @ media max-width not working correctly

Tags: html, css, media

Just having an issue using the css syntax:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1085px){
   .page-content {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: auto;
    }

    .welcome-header{
        grid-column-end: span 1;

    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that its not changing the actual 'grid-column-end' to 'span 1' when originally, it was 'span 2'.

What is it that i'm doing wrong here?

Thanks :)

Code:

```
.page-content div{
    background-color: #8fb8de;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #406e8e;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 230px;
}

.welcome-header{
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #30292f;

}
```

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try `min-width: 1085px`, Also avoid using percentage values when defining your columns, and use [Fr Unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

Comment: What is the intended behaviour of your media query?